# What's the fastest way to replicate a MySQL database from one machine to another?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

What's the fastest way to replicate a MySQL database from one machine to another? The two machines are connected via LAN.  How to do it without `mysqldump`?

If using `mysqldump`, is the fastest way

```
$ mysqldump -h localhost -u foo -pbar mydb > mydb.sql
```

and then copy `mydb.sql` to desination machine and do

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u foo -pbar < mydb.sql
```

?   When importing, do I need to specify the database?

Comment: Are you trying to simply copy data over, or are you trying to set up replication?

Comment: The fastest way would be to stop mysql, copy over the data directory, then start mysql on the new computer. That would require downtime on the source, though.

Comment: I just want to copy data.

Comment: How to determine what files to copy to the target?

Comment: @user001 Usually just the whole /var/lib/mysql directory.  It is configurable though, check your my.cnf file (usually /etc/mysql/my.cnf) for the datadir variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally do it in one step with a pipe using mysqldump like so

```
mysqldump -u user_source -p --opt database_name table_name | mysql -u user_target -p --host=target_db_ip -C target_database
```

but if mysqldump is not allowed just save the dump somewhere you can access it then use wget to move it to the other server and unpack there using mysql.  I normally use this command because it doesn't require me to stop the database and is a single command with no files rather than a process where I have to manage where the data files are.

Comment: What does `--opt` do?  After the pipe, can I use `mysql -h target_db_ip -u user_target -p -C new_table`?  Also, which database will the table be created in on the target?

Comment: [--opt](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) is a combination of several things like remove a table of this name if it exists already in the target, etc. the -C means compress the table in transit for faster transfer and the database in the target will be the same as the database in the source by default unless you specify otherwise

Comment: What if the database under same name does not exist on the target machine?  Will it be automatically created?

Comment: Not 100% sure, I have always just gone into phpmyadmin on the target and made the database by hand then used this command to get the tables I want copied over but I am sure it will mention somewhere in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)